# Python の subprocess で実行中プロセスの戻り値をリアルタイムに取得したい

Tags: python, subprocess

subprocessにてあるコマンドを実行した時、端末から実行した時同様
リアルタイムに戻り値を取得、表示したいのですがどうしたら良いのでしょうか

試したコード
(実際の実行コマンドとは別ですが正常に実行されています)

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
    
cmd='ping 127.0.0.1'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
while proc.poll() is None:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print(line)
```

実行中何も表示されず、処理終了後に一括で表示されてしまいます

Comment: 戻り値というかPIPE出力の結果ですよね。これらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[How to get realtime Python subprocess output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64175492/9014308), [Get realtime output from python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29433250/9014308), [Getting realtime output using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/803265/9014308)

Comment: リンク先の回答をいくつか試したところ解決できました　ありがとうございます

Comment: 実際に解決した方法を自己回答してみてください。実例を示すのも良い情報共有になるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます　自己回答させていただきました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決できました
[Getting realtime output using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess)

Linux環境特有っぽいですが stdbuf を通して実行するだけでした

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
    
cmd='ping 127.0.0.1'
cmd='stdbuf -oL '+cmd
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
while proc.poll() is None:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print(line)
```

また、shell=True を無くした以下のコードでもOKでした

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
    
cmd = ["ping", "127.0.0.1"]
cmd = ["stdbuf", "-oL"] + cmd
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
while proc.poll() is None:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print(line)
```

ちなみに教えていただいた先の回答で
for文を while文に変えただけでは特に変化なし
subprocess.Popenの引数を色々追加しても駄目でした